# Problema al eliminar clave foranea laravel

Tags: laravel, delete

Tengo un controlador en mi proyecto en donde una tabla está asociada a otra, o sea, tengo una tabla evaluadores y una tabla evaluación.

Actualmente estoy dando la posibilidad de eliminar el registro de evaluadores aunque esté asociado a una evaluación.
Para esto estoy utilizando

```
public function destroy(Evaluadores $evaluadores)
{
     Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints(); 
        $evaluadores->delete();                 
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints(); 
        return response()->json(ok, 200);
}
```

Mi pregunta es más que nada si esto es una mala práctica y algo que no debo realizar. Si no hay problema con utilizar este método o si hay alguna otra forma de realizarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que es una mala práctica o mala decisión es como quedarán tus datos después de eliminar registros de esta manera. Yo te sugeriría usar SoftDeletes, así pudieras recuperar los evaluadores y aunque no los recuperes, al menos mantendrás tus datos mejor. Si de cualquier modo quieres eliminarlos, deberías destruir primero la relación entre esos registros, dejando null tu campo en evaluaiones pues ese evaluador ya no existe. Como hablas de Prácticas, eso puede ser un poco subjetivo con lo cual trato de darte solo algunas ideas para tomar la decisión más conveniente para tu proyecto.